# Can I use Student's T distribution in rainier?

Tags: scala, statistics, bayesian, probabilistic-programming

I want to get started with the statistical framework Rainier. There's a list of [pre-built distribution](https://rainier.fit/docs/distributions) that does not include Student's T, which I need for my project. How can I use a custom distribution as a prior to my model?

Comment: Most likely by implementing [`Distribution`](https://github.com/stripe/rainier/blob/af6aba7e7ed6d791b90e5e1bde2a798c50524908/rainier-core/src/main/scala/com/stripe/rainier/core/Distribution.scala) interface and picking your implementation.

Comment: I think that's right, thanks. Couldn't find any documentation on the methods for this trait so I am trying to guess by looking at already implemented distributions.